# Read the value returned by a function without updating it?

Tags: python

I have some code that will update and return a value every fifteen seconds.

```
def set_interval(func, sec):
    def func_wrapper():
        set_interval(func, sec)
        func()
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t

def gem_price():
    return random.randint(1,1000)
    print ("Updated")

set_interval(gem_price, 15)
```

Later within the code, I want to output the value that was returned by the function 'gem_price'. The way I've been going about this is by printing the function itself.

```
print(gem_price())
```

The problem I have is, everytime I output the 'gem_price' using this method, it will update the value. I would like to able to output the value without having to update it.

Is there any way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You seem to be very confused. You are not printing "the function"; you are printing *the result of calling* the function. And there is nothing that is getting "updated" at all. If you want to remember the value that was returned *a specific time* that the function was called, then you have to... remember it, by giving it a name.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print value after every 15 sec, you can use this:

```
import time

while True: 
    ...
    Yourcode
    ...
    print('The answer is....', answer)
    time.sleep(15)
```

Answer (score 0):

`gem_price()` just returns a random integer between 1 and 1000 every time it is called. It does not store anything.
If you want to store this value, just assign it to a variable: `value = gem_price()` and then use this variable and not the function (unless you want another value, but to keep it you should assign it to another var).
It seems you don't completely understand how functions work, by the way. A variable inside of a function gets deleted when the function exits (generally). Also, the execution flow stops after the `return` statement, so your `print` is never reached and thus never executed.

You should read [this part of the Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions). Actually, all of it.